# how to convert array to BindingList

Tags: c#, type-conversion, bindinglist

What is the easiest and fastest way to convert an array to BindingList?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the `BindingList` constructor that takes an `IList<T>`.

```
var binding = new BindingList<MyType>(myArray);
```

Answer (score 4):

You're looking for the [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132683.aspx):

```
var bl = new BindingList<YourClass>(arr);
```

Comment: did not understand, can you give an example?

Answer (score 3):

Be careful when using the BindingList(IList ..) constructor with an Array as the IList will be read-only.

Any attempts to add/remove from the BindingList will therefore throw a NotSupportedException as the IList can't handle the functionality as the Collection is read-only.

To create an editable BindingList you'll have to convert it to a list before using the IList constructor.

A nice description as to why Arrays are built from IList can be found here for some additional reading: 
[Why array implements IList?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5968708/why-array-implements-ilist)

Answer (score 1):

you can try a foreach cycle:

```
    public void AppenFromArray(T[] aSource)
    {
        if (aSource == null) { return; }

        foreach (T el in aSource)
        {
            this.Add(el);
        }
    }
```