# Why array implements IList?

Tags: c#, arrays, ilist, liskov-substitution-principle

See the definition of *System.Array* class

```
public abstract class Array : IList, ...
```

Theoretically, I should be able to write this bit and be happy

```
int[] list = new int[] {};
IList iList = (IList)list;
```

I also should be able to call any method from the iList

```
 ilist.Add(1); //exception here
```

My question is not why I get an exception, but rather **why Array implements IList**?

Comment: **Good** question. I never liked the idea of fat interfaces (that’s the technical term for this kind of design).

Comment: The real (better) question would be why it supports `IList<T>`. `IList` is legacy.

Comment: How do you think it breaks substitution? I think it doesn't. See Brians answer.

Comment: @Henk, see: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2004/11/19/267089.aspx

Comment: Does anybody actually care about LSP? It seems quite academic to me.

Comment: @Gabe, then you need to work with larger codebases. Implementing a behavior (inheriting from an interface) and then simply ignoring the things you don't like/can't support leads to smelly, obfuscated, casting and finally: buggy code.

Comment: @Marius: You have to put the complexity somewhere. Let's say you have a method that can sort a member of its class. With a single `IList<>` interface, you can check `IsReadOnly` to see if you can sort. If you have separate `IRWList<>` and `IReadList<>` interfaces, what type do you make the member of your class? You can't use `IRWList<>` because then it couldn't hold read-only objects, so you have to make it a `IReadList<>` and then cast to `IRWList` to do your sorting. See -- smelly, obfuscated casting.

Comment: @Gabe its the collection which implies mutability not its contained entities. You can make your class member of a type that implements both IRWList<> and IReadList<>, use if as IRWList<> internally in your class and expose it as IReadList. Yes, you have to put complexity somewhere, but I just don't see how that applies to disregarding LSP as a very good design principle (did not know about the IsReadOnly property though which makes IList more complex from a consumers standpoint)

Answer (score 108, accepted):

Because an array allows fast access by index, and `IList`/`IList<T>` are the only collection interfaces that support this. So perhaps your real question is "Why is there no interface for constant collections with indexers?" And to that I have no answer.

There are no readonly interfaces for collections either. And I'm missing those even more than a constant sized with indexers interface.

IMO there should be several more (generic) collection interfaces depending on the features of a collection. And the names should have been different too, `List` for something with an indexer is really stupid IMO.

- Just Enumeration `IEnumerable<T>`
- Readonly but no indexer (.Count, .Contains,...)
- Resizable but no indexer, i.e. set like (Add, Remove,...) current `ICollection<T>`
- Readonly with indexer (indexer, indexof,...)
- Constant size with indexer (indexer with a setter)
- Variable size with indexer (Insert,...) current `IList<T>`

I think the current collection interfaces are bad design. But since they have properties telling you which methods are valid (and this is part of the contract of these methods), it doesn't break the substitution principle.

Comment: thanks for the answer. But I rather leave the question as is. The reason is simple. Interface is a public contract. If one implements it, one must fully implement all the members, otherwise it breaks LSP and generally smells bad, is it not?

Comment: @olek But there is no good alternative to `IList<T>` atm since this is the only collection interface with an indexer. And all the code that needs an indexer thus uses `IList<T>`, in particular many linq methods do(Skip,ElementAt,Reverse,...)

Comment: It does break LSP. If it didn't list.Add(item) should add item to the list regardless of the concrete type. Except for exceptionel cases. In the array implementation in throws an exception in a non-exceptionel case, which in it self is bad practice

Comment: @RuneFS it doesn't break LSP, you're just using it wrong. You should be checking IsFixedSize or IsReadOnly before attempting to mutate the object.

Comment: @smelch I'm sorry but you got LSP wrong then. An array does not implement `add` and thus can't be substituted for something that does when that ability is required.

Comment: I concede that it *technically* does not violate LSP *only because* the documentation states you should check the `IsFixedSize` and `IsReadOnly` properties, it definitely violates the *Tell, Don't Ask principle* and *Principle of least surprise*.  Why implement an interface when you're just going to throw exceptions for 4 out of the 9 methods?

Comment: Some time has passed since the original question. But now with .Net 4.5, there are additional interfaces [IReadOnlyList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh192385.aspx) and [IReadOnlyCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh881542.aspx).

Comment: Very simply this was done to avoid breaking changes which people would have complained about a lot more vocally than this.

Comment: it does not breaks LSP if you check IsReadonly or IsFixedSize but it violate Open/Close. check LSP here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4428725/can-you-explain-liskov-substitution-principle-with-a-good-c-sharp-example

Answer (score 46):

The remarks section of the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ilist#remarks) for `IList` says:

> IList is a descendant of the
> ICollection interface and is the base
> interface of all non-generic lists.
> **IList implementations fall into three
> categories: read-only, fixed-size, and
> variable-size**. A read-only IList
> cannot be modified. A fixed-size IList
> does not allow the addition or removal
> of elements, but it allows the
> modification of existing elements. A
> variable-size IList allows the
> addition, removal, and modification of
> elements.

Obviously, arrays fall into the fixed-size category, so by the definition of the interface it makes sense.

Comment: I guess they would have ended up with a lot of interfaces. IListFixedSize, IListReadOnly...

Comment: that'a actually a good answer from the documentation's point of view. But to me it rather looks like a hack. Interfaces must be thin and simple in order for a class to implement all the members.

Comment: @oleksii: I agree. Interfaces and runtime exceptions are not the most elegant combination. In defense of `Array` it does implement the `Add` method explicitly, which reduces the risk of calling it by accident.

Comment: Until we create an implementation of `IList` that disallows both modification *and* addition/removal. Then the documentations is no longer correct. :P

Comment: @Magnus - In .Net 4.5, there are additional interfaces [IReadOnlyList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh192385.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and [IReadOnlyCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh881542.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Comment: @RBT But afaik, unfortunately not the opposite to exclude collections that can't be written to.

Comment: @BrianRasmussen unless you were trying to expose an interface to not force a concrete implementation.

Answer (score 19):

Because **not all `IList`s are mutable** (see `IList.IsFixedSize` and `IList.IsReadOnly`), and arrays certainly behave like fixed-size lists.

If your question is really "why does it implement a *non-generic* interface", then the answer is that these were around before generics came along.

Comment: @oleksii: No, it doesn't break LSP, because the interface `IList` *itself* tells you that it may not be mutable. If it was in fact guaranteed to be mutable and the array told you otherwise, *then* it would break the rule.

Comment: Actually, Array does break LSP in case of generic `IList<T>` and doesn't break it in case of non-generic `IList`: http://enterprisecraftsmanship.com/2014/11/22/read-only-collections-and-lsp/

Answer (score 6):

It's a legacy that we have from the times when it wasn't clear how to deal with read only collections and whether or not Array is read only. There are IsFixedSize and IsReadOnly flags in the IList interface. IsReadOnly flag means that collection can't be changed at all and IsFixedSize means that collection does allow modification, but not adding or removal of items.

At the time of .Net 4.5 it was clear that some "intermediate" interfaces are required to work with read only collections, so `IReadOnlyCollection<T>` and `IReadOnlyList<T>` were introduced.

Here is a great blog post describing the details: [Read only collections in .NET](http://enterprisecraftsmanship.com/2014/11/22/read-only-collections-and-lsp/)

Comment: An array is not read only you can simply set values at indexes. An array just has a fixed size but there  isn't an `IFixedSizeList` .

Answer (score 0):

Definition of IList interface is "Represents a non-generic collection of objects that can be individually accessed by index.". Array completely satisfies this definition, so must implement the interface.
Exception when calling Add() method is "System.NotSupportedException: Collection was of a fixed size" and occurred because array can not increase its capacity dynamically. Its capacity is defined during creation of array object.

Answer (score 0):

Having an array implement IList (and transitively, ICollection) simplified the Linq2Objects engine, since casting the IEnumerable to IList/ICollection would also work for arrays.

For example, a Count() ends up calling the Array.Length under-the-hood, since it's casted to ICollection and the array's implementation returns Length.

Without this, the Linq2Objects engine would not have special treatment for arrays and perform horribly, or they'd need to double the code adding special-case treatment for arrays (like they do for IList).  They must've opted to make array implement IList instead.

That's my take on "Why".

Answer (score 0):

Also implementation details LINQ Last checks for IList , if it did not implement list they would need either 2 checks slowing down all Last calls or have Last on an Array taking O(N)

Answer (score 0):

An `Array` is just one of many possible implementations of `IList`.

As code should be loosely coupled, depend on abstractions and what not... The concrete implementation of `IList` that uses consecutive memory (an array) to store it's values is called `Array`. We do not "add" `IList` to the `Array` class that's just the wrong order of reasoning; `Array` implements `IList` as an array.

The exception is exactly what the interface defines. It is not a surprise if you know the whole interface not just a single method. The interface also give you the opportunity to check the `IsFixedSize` property and see if it is safe to call the `Add` method.