# Why do core types implement interfaces only partly?

Tags: c#, .net, collections, interface

**Q1** Why do new classes from .NET implement interfaces only partially?

**Q2** Shall I do the same in my code?

I asked this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5968708/why-array-implements-ilist), so I thought, okay that was long time ago, you can have different usage etc etc, and now such implementation is supported only for consistency reasons. But new classes also do that.

**Old**

```
int[] list = new int[] {};
IList iList = (IList)list;
ilist.Add(1); //exception here
```

**New**

```
ICollection c = new ConcurrentQueue<int>();
var root = c.SyncRoot; //exception here
```

UPDATE

I am not worried **why** I get exceptions, it is clear. But I don't understand **why** classes **implement** the well defined contract, but not all the members (which can lead to unpleasant run time exceptions)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could argue that the interfaces weren't granular enough in the original design. For example, most people ***never use*** `SyncRoot` - it could perhaps have been on a different interface. Likewise, it is unfortunate that no interface offers read-only indexer access, for example.

As it stands, the interfaces are what they are. It is still very convenient to implement the main `IList[<T>]`/`ICollection[<T>]`/`IEnumerable[<T>]` interfaces though - it offers the *majority* of callers access to what they need... so *indexers* in the first example, and `Add` in the second.

To be fair, they do also offer `IsFixedSize` and `IsReadOnly` - querying the first would have led you to not call `Add`. Re `SyncRoot` - that presumably can't make sense inside `ConcurrentQueue<T>`, and any implementation would break the logic of the type. Normally I would say "then it isn't that type; don't implement the interface", but to repeat my earlier statement...  ***most people never use `SyncRoot`*** - so I'm OK with it ;p

Comment: **most people never use**  `SyncRoot` doesn't answer the questions. I can just have the classes to declare public methods with the same names as in interface, but I won't add properties/methods that don't make sense (like `Add` or `SyncRoot` from my samples)

Comment: The lack of an IReadableByIndex method is IMHO a significant weakness in .net, one which considerably weakens the usefulness of contravariance (IReadableByIndex could be contravariant even though IList cannot).  I suspect the limitation stems from the fact that a class which has a ReadOnly property and a WriteOnly property can't be treated as having a ReadWrite property, though I don't know any reason why compilers couldn't simply have reads use a ReadOnly property and writes use a WriteOnly property; I would think that would have made many things more convenient.

Answer (score 2):

One minor point, all interfaces have to be fully implemented.  All methods and properties of an interface must be implemented by any implementor – otherwise the compiler. You are referring to the runtime errors that can be thrown when you call some methods of an interface.

The documentation for `IList` states:

> IList is a descendant of the ICollection interface and is the base interface of all non-generic lists. IList implementations fall into three categories: read-only, fixed-size, and variable-size. A read-only IList cannot be modified. A fixed-size IList does not allow the addition or removal of elements, but it allows the modification of existing elements. A variable-size IList allows the addition, removal, and modification of elements.

When you call a method that cannot be satisfied by a particular implementation then you get an exception.

Why was the interface designed this way?  One can only speculate, but this particular design allows for the `IsFixedSize`, `IsReadOnly` etc. properties to change during the lifetime of an instance of the interface.

Should you design your interfaces this way?  That depends on whether such a design is desirable and meets your needs.

Comment: It kind of undermines the idea behind an interface though. It is supposed to define a common set of operations that you can rely on existing for any type that implements the interface, so that you can switch between different implementations of the interface, and they'll all, well, *work*. Saying "We don't implement this, so have an exception instead" makes the interface somewhat pointless.

Comment: Don't worry, I try not to shoot any messengers. :) Although I'd point out that with the last paragraph, you're a bit more than a messenger, since you actually take a stand on whether it is (or can be) good design

Comment: @jalf As soon as you allow mutable types, then I think you are accepting such designs as viable

Comment: @David, so what is the problem in **implement just those members that are required, and don't force the class to implement the interface that is not fully supported**? Why can I not simply have public methods that are not from the interface?

Comment: Your implementing class can have methods not in the interface. But you must implement all methods of the interface. Or do I not understand your question?

Comment: The design of IList does mean that IsFixedSize, IsReadOnly, etc. are mutable, but IMHO that's not a good thing.  A program that wants to avoid exceptions should not have to check those properties every time it wants to write to a collection.

Comment: @David You are 100% correct, I am just wondering why force a class to throw an exception on the interface method that is not support

Comment: @oleksii What would the alternative be? The design of interfaces is based around the idea that the entire interface (i.e. all methods) must be implemented.

Comment: @David, I will just drop the interface from class "signature", e.g. for the `Array` I will remove the `IList` implementation, but I will keep most of the public methods named as in `IList` (and remove the ones that don't make sense, like `Add()`). Is that a bad idea?

Comment: if you don't need to implement IList then you can and should do this.

Answer (score 1):

From OOP standpoint this is simply wrong. They should either have made smaller interfaces or not put them on stuff like Arrays. However the .NET Framework designers are not stupid and they probably made some tradeoff. For example IEnumerable is required to implement IDisposable which does not make sense from OOP design standpoint but there are some performance benefits for database readers for example. So probably implementations that are hacked into a class (like your example) have some benefit but from OOP point of view they are wrong and you should not do it unless you are aware what you are trading the good design for.

Comment: `IEnumerable` is *not* required to implement `IDisposable`, and neither is `IEnumerator`. `IEnumerator<T>` is, and that has paid dividends over-and-over when you think about things like "iterator blocks" with `finally`.

Comment: Still doesn't change the fact that as an OOP design the requirement to have a possibly empty disposle method sucks. I don't say that the decision to add it is wrong. I just say that they traded OOP design for other benefits. BTW the Reset method plainly sucks and MS has admitted it was a mistake:)

Comment: yep, absolutely agree with you there;

Comment: @Stilgar: It was necessary to do one of three things: (1) Accept that any type which cannot create enumerators which can be safely abandoned without consequence cannot legitimately implement `IEnumerable`; (2) Require that any code which calls `GetEnumerator()` call `Dispose` check whether the actual object it returns implements `IDisposable` and call `Dispose` on it if so; (3) Require that any code which calls `GetEnumerator` call `Dispose` on the result (which it will be able to do) and require that enumerators implement `IDisposable`.  I would consider option #3 to be the least evil.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the existence of partially-implemented interfaces is a consequence of a design decision not to allow a class or interface to have independent readable property and writable properties of the same name and automatically use them appropriately (e.g. if a class has a readable property 'foo' and a writable property 'foo', use the readable property for reads and the writable one for writes).  This design decision made it awkward to split off the reading and writing aspects of certain interfaces.

Ideally, instead of having a single interface IList, there would have been generic contravariant interface IReadableByIndex, generic covariant interfaces IWriteableByIndex, IAppendable, IGrowableByIndex (includes various insert and delete functions), and non-generic IMovableByIndex (index-based copy, swap, and roll functions) and maybe IComparableByIndex (given two indices, compare the items).  An interface IList could implement all of those, but there would be many useful subsets as well (many of which could be contravariant or covariant).  Note that the existence of some non-generic routines would allow things like sorts to be implemented on any collection that implements IComparableByIndex and IMovableByIndex without having to worry about the exact type of the collection.

Unfortunately, for a split of IList to have been really useful, it would have been necessary to have IReadableByIndex and IWritableByIndex as separate interfaces.  This in turn would have posed difficulties when trying to write code that would inherit both interfaces, as the compiler would complain about ambiguity when trying to use the indexed accessor.  Since the IReadableByIndex and IWritableByIndex ended up having to be combined, Microsoft probably figured it may as well lump everything into IList.