# IList trouble. Fixed size?

Tags: c#, collections, ilist

I have this code :

```
IList<string> stelle = stelleString.Split('-');

if (stelle.Contains("3"))
    stelle.Add("8");

if (stelle.Contains("4"))
    stelle.Add("6");
```

but seems that IList have a fixed size after a .Split() : *System.NotSupportedException: Collection was of a fixed size.*

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: `string.Split()` returns a string array. Arrays are of fixed size, hence the exception you're getting.

Comment: This is due to bad design decisions in .NET: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5968708/why-array-implements-ilist/5968798#5968798

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The `Split` method returns an array, and you can't resize an array.

You can create a `List<string>` from the array using the `ToList` extension method:

```
IList<string> stelle = stelleString.Split('-').ToList();
```

or the `List<T>` constructor:

```
IList<string> stelle = new List<string>(stelleString.Split('-'));
```

Besides, you probably don't want to use the `IList<T>` interface as the type of the variable, but just use the actual type of the object:

```
string[] stelle = stelleString.Split('-');
```

or:

```
List<string> stelle = stelleString.Split('-').ToList();
```

This will let you use exactly what the class can do, not limited to the `IList<T>` interface, and no methods that are not supported.

Comment: This could be a problem if the stelleString is "". I should put it on a try catch....

Comment: @markzzz: If the string doesn't contain the delimiter, the `Split` method returns an array with a single item, containing the original string. If you want to handle that differently, a `try...catch` won't help, you have to check `Count` of the list.

Answer (score 13):

`string.Split` returns a string *array*. This would indeed have a fixed size.

You can convert it to a `List<string>` by passing the result to the `List<T>` constructor:

```
IList<string> stelle = new List<string>(stelleString.Split('-'));
```

Or, if available, you can use the LINQ `ToList()` operator:

```
IList<string> stelle = stelleString.Split('-').ToList();
```

Comment: Sounds like System.Array implements IList<T> syntactically but not semantically.  Unfortunate.

Answer (score 3):

It has a fixed size cause [string.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx) returns a string[]. You need to pass the return value of split to a List<string> instance to support adding additional elements.

Answer (score 2):

Call `ToList()` to the result:

```
IList<string> stelle = stelleString.Split('-').ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

String.split return an array. But you can redimensionate array. In VB it is

```
ReDim perserve myarray(newlength minus one)
```