# int[] qualifies as IList<T>?

Tags: c#

In a different question on stackoverflow somebody suggested to write an extension method for an array, but used the `this IList<T>` interface in the extension method. I commented it should be an array but he declined. I tested it, and of course, he's right... :)

Extension method:

```
public static void Fill<T>(this IList<T> array, T value)
{
    for(var i = 0; i < array.Count; i++) 
    {
        array[i] = value;
    }
}
```

Test code:

```
[Test] 
public void Stackoverflow()
{
    int[] arr = new int[] { 1,2,3,4};
    arr.Fill(2);
    Assert.AreEqual(2, arr[0]);
    Assert.AreEqual(2, arr[1]);
    Assert.AreEqual(2, arr[2]);
    Assert.AreEqual(2, arr[3]);
}
```

An `array` is not an `IList<T>`. Why does this even compile? Let alone, pass?!

Comment: You need to be clearer between `IList` (which `Array` implements) and `IList<T>` (which it doesn't, but which all specific array types do).

Comment: yeah sorry done that now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From section 12.1.2 of the C# 4 specification:

> A one-dimensional array `T[]` implements the interface `System.Collections.Generic.IList<T>` and its base interfaces. Accordingly, there is an implicit conversion from `T[]` to `IList<T>` and its base interfaces.

It's worth noting that if you create a rectangular array *or* a one-dimensional array which has a lower bound other than zero, those do *not* implement `IList<T>`.

In the CLI, there are actually two terms: *vector* and *array*. A vector is a one-dimensional collection with a lower bound of zero, and is optimized to heck and back by the JIT. An array can have multiple dimensions and different lower bounds, and isn't subject to as thorough optimization.

A `T[]` in C# is *always* a vector. You can't cast an object which is a CLI-array to `T[]` - you end up with an exception like this:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type
'System.String[*]' to type 'System.String[]'.
```

Comment: That last sentence is interesting.. I did not know that! You are an incredible source of information.

Comment: Other than the obvious answer of "Because he is Jon Skeet".. how do you find all of this information? I love all of these implementation details and other than the book "Pro .NET Performance" I've found it hard to come across this level of detail.

Comment: well he wrote the book "C# in Depth, Second Edition" for starters ;-). I should read it probably. Thanks for the clarification and for the help in asking the correct question :). +1 + accept

Comment: @bas That is a contender for "because he is Jon Skeet". I guess my question was more .. how does he come across the material for the book and these sorts of answers. I can't seem to find this level of detail documented anywhere. I'm fascinated by this sort of information.. so its kinda frustrating for me having to wait for these questions to be asked and this level of answer to be given :P

Comment: @SimonWhitehead: Reading the CLI spec in this case :)

Comment: @JonSkeet It is probably time I got stuck into the specs I think. Thanks!

Comment: It's also funny that a so-called `String[*]`, i.e. a one-dimensional string array whose index is not zero-based, works with the non-generic `IList` interface. For example: `System.Collections.IList arr = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(string), new[] { 21, }, new[] { -10, }); arr[-7] = "works";` And a multi-dimensional (possibly zero-based) array does implement non-generic `IList`, bot using [the indexer (which has only one index parameter)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ilist.item.aspx) fails run-time, of course.

Comment: @JonSkeet I don't know how else to get in contact with you. Your third edition can be ordered in MEAP (no idea what it means). If I order it, will it be an ebook only as amazon states? Do I need to wait to get a hard-copy? If there is a more appropriate place for this question let me know and my sincere apologies for asking it here.

Comment: @bas: MEAP=Manning Early Access Program. You can order either ebook or hard copy; if you buy the hard copy you'll get the ebook free. If you order the MEAP you won't get hard copy until the final book is ready, of course, but you get the "preview" version of the ebook immediately. For more details, email me (skeet@pobox.com)

Answer (score 6):

`Array` doesn't implement `IList<T>`, but `T[]` does, thanks to some runtime magic. Arrays are a bit weird since should have been generic, but predate the generic system and thus use specialized hacks.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT: Originally thought the OP was asking about `IList` and not `IList<T>`.**

...because arrays implement `IList`:

```
public abstract class Array : ICloneable, IList, ICollection, IEnumerable, IStructuralComparable, IStructuralEquatable
//                                        ^^^^^
```

Comment: The question is slightly misleading, but the extension method is on `IList<T>`, which `Array` *doesn't* implement.

Comment: @JonSkeet Ah, indeed. The OP appears to switch between `IList` and `IList<T>` throughout the question..

Answer (score 1):

On a slightly related note:

It's quite unfortunate that T[] implements IList<T> sometimes. Consider the following code:

```
int[] array = new int[10];
IList<int> list = array; // Compiles
list.Add(1);             // Runtime error. Ew!
```

Not very nice really.

For this reason, you need to think carefully before using IList<T> instead of T[].

Comment: The underlying problem is that the collection interfaces are badly designed. Related: [Why array implements IList?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5968708/why-array-implements-ilist)