# IList<T> array and Collection is read-only ERROR

Tags: c#, .net

During fixing bug in one project find interesting issue

```
IList<int> a =new List<int>();
var b = new int[2];
b[0] = 1;
b[1] = 2;
a = b;
a.Clear();
```

This code is throws exception on a.Clear();
I know how to fix it but I didn't clearly get all steps which leads to this NotSupported exception. And why compiler didn't throws compile time error?

Comment: Since `a` is an interface type.

Comment: @SrinivasReddyThatiparthy - It's nothing to do with it being an interface type.

Comment: @Enigmativity if `a` was `List<int>` rather than `IList<int>` it would not have worked.

Comment: @Magnus - It's nothing to do with `IList<int>`. It's because the underlying type is an `int[]`. If the underlying type were `List<int>` it would have worked fine despite being an `IList<int>`.

Comment: @Enigmativity What I meant was that if `a` var declared as `List<int> a = new List<int>();` There would be a compilation error on `a = b;`

Comment: @Magnus - Ah, I see. My apologies.

Answer (score 12):

Yes, this is a somewhat annoying feature of standard C# arrays: They implement `IList<>`, as defined by the C# language.

Because of this, you can assign a standard C# array to an `IList<>` type, and the compiler will not complain (because according to the language, an array IS-A `IList<>`).

Alas, this means that you can then try to do something to change the array such as `IList<>.Clear()` or `IList<>.Add()` and you will get a runtime error.

For some discussion about *why* the language is defined like this, see the following thread:

[Why array implements IList?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5968708/why-array-implements-ilist)