# Pass either List<string> or string[ ] array to a C# method

Tags: c#, collections, parameter-passing

I have the following method in my C# class.

*For the parameter called 'collections'* I would like to have the flexibility of either passing a List or string[ ] array. 
I know I could simply set the parameter type as object type, but **is there any other more efficient type I could use to do this?**

```
public string ProcessDoc(List<string> collections, string userName)
{
  //code goes here
   string result = null;
   ...
   ...
   return result;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use [`IList<string>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5y536ey6(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
public string ProcessDoc(IList<string> collections, string userName)
{
  //code goes here
   string result = null;
   ...
   ...
   return result;
}
```

[Why array implements IList?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5968708/why-array-implements-ilist)

Comment: So I could just pass an array like ProcessDoc( new string[] {"x", "y","z"}, "sun") ?

Comment: Ok. So Array and List implement IList interface, and that is the reason we can use IList in this case. Thanks.

Comment: If indexer is not a requirement then `IEnumerable<string>` is more encompassing alternative.

Comment: @Dialecticus, I need the indexer in my C# method.

Comment: @Dialecticus: i wanted to give the highest common factor, also  `IList<string>` implements `IEnumerable<string>`.